# Automatically refreshing web page after music finishes playing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a site where you are given random music to listen to every time you refresh a page. That works just fine but is it possible to some how grab the length of the currently playing track and set the page to reload itself when it finishes playing?

Thanks in advance!

I'm for now just using the basic html audio tag:

```
theMusic[0] = '<audio controls autoplay><source src= "1.ogg"></audio>';
theMusic[1] = '<audio controls autoplay><source src= "2.ogg"></audio>';
theMusic[2] = '<audio controls autoplay><source src= "3.ogg"></audio>';

var i = Math.floor(3*Math.random())
```

Comment: What are you using to play the music? Do you have any code we could check?

Comment: Please edit your original post with this code for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `<audio>` element's `onended` event to reload the page:

```
<audio controls autoplay onended="javascript:window.location.reload();">
[...]
</audio>
```